# Odd Symbol showing up in file names Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, special-characters

I installed 16.04 and was setting it up and moving some files from an external drive (Fat32 and made in OSX).

Some of the files display this very odd character on Xubuntu 14.04

I think these symbols appear in place of periods or some periods it seems

[image: example of odd character]

When I copy and paste the name from Properties, it shows up as the Yeti head looking symbol in most places including terminal

In IRC and Firefoxes url bar it displays as a box with `FO` on top and `22` on bottom inside the box like this:

[image: display of character]

In shell it shows the weird symbol as: `"` instead of the yeti head or the `FO22` box when I do an `ls` to that directory

Comment: The downvotes are probably because people, looking at the title, think you are asking an elementary OS problem, which is off-topic here. But since you also have it on Xubuntu, I don't think it off topic.

Comment: Here, have an upvote (for the above-mentioned reasons).'

Comment: Don't add "why was this downvoted" to the question, it just makes it hard to read, use comments. The downvotes are due to people just seeing EOS and jumping on it, we ONLY support the *buntus, I remove all references to EOS, that should stop the downvotes.

Comment: I guess that that is because of the encoding. What encoding did you use on OSX? And what encoding did you choose when mounting the partition?

Comment: Thanks for explanations everyone. I was disheartened to see it go into the negatives and not know why. I thought including that another OS did the same thing (one with an Ubuntu heritage like Elementary Freya) would be helpful. Thanks for helping with title @Mark Kirby.

Comment: @dadexix I don't know what encoding I used. I don't recall changing it so default would be my guess. I don't have that laptop right now to check. I also never chose an encoding when mounting...I just plugged the drive in to the Xubuntu 16.04 and saw these symbols.

Comment: Well, there is no "default", every OS decides by itself what to choose... In the original FAT there is no Unicode support, so is Mac uses it (and I have no idea about it, look on the manual) you might need to force it in Ubuntu as well,, have a look for example [here](http://www.nslu2-linux.org/wiki/HowTo/MountFATFileSystems). If your Mac uses a different encoding, than you should modify the above commands appropriately.